# Ubuntu 16.04 booted to BusyBox, fsck repaired, now sudoers.so file has no contents

Tags: busybox, initramfs

Upon bootup, my Ubuntu 16.04 system booted to busybox (`initramfs`). I ran fsck on the boot drive, found and resolved errors. The system now boots fine, but I am unable to do anything as sudo. I get the following error:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin `sudoers_policy'
sudo: unable to load /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so: file too short
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

`/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` now contains no content. The file ownership and permission appear to be fine. Is there a way to rebuild the file?

Comment: Download the sudo*.deb package, then overwrite files with correct ones.